# Auto-incrementig rows in horizontal drag

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I got this table,

```
         A         |       B
1     =Sheet2!$C5
2
```

Now I want to drag A1, to B1 and increment the row count.
So the expected result would be

```
         A         |       B
1     =Sheet2!$C5     =Sheet2!$C6
2
```

But instead it just copies the entire cell in form of `=Sheet2!$C5` inside both A1 and B1.
Any idea how to turn on horizontal autoincrement for the formulas here?

---

EDIT: Obviously in my actual project I'm doing this on much larger scale, so no, manually incrementing is not an option. I also tried using offset, but it didn't want to increment either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `OFFSET`. For example, place this in `A1` and drag across:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$C5,COLUMN(A:A)-1,)
```

If you want to completely flip your dragging - that is, across goes down and vica versa, try this:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$C$5,COLUMN(A:A)-1,ROW(1:1)-1)
```

Comment: This autoincrements the columns (eg. if I drag you formula to B1 in example, it changes to COLUMN(B:B)-1). This however doesn't correctly retrieve the values from the sheet 2. And if you hard fix it with a $sign instead, it locks the entire row without auto-incrementig, which leads to my initial issue as i described. - as I've said in my edit, i tried using offset before posting as well and it didn't work (unless I'm doing something horribly wrong)

Comment: @Rawrplus The autoincrementing is exactly what makes it work. Dragging across by one column makes it `=OFFSET(Sheet2!$C5,COLUMN(B:B)-1,)` >> `=OFFSET(Sheet2!$C5,2-1,)` >> `=OFFSET(Sheet2!$C5,1,)` - offsetting by one row. I've tested this and it works *exactly* as described in your question

Comment: I don't know... I do understand how offset works, but I still can't get correct values. It seems to copy the exact same value (which is C5, into the adjacent rows). What I want is to Increment the C5 to C6 to C7 etc. But I keep getting C5. Which is exactly what I thought offset was supposed to do with the 1 index for row as +1, but it just doesn't seem to increment

Comment: @Rawrplus I’d suggest this: create a simple example and test these formulas — they work! Then figure out how your main problem differs from your simple example :)